# How to remove white border from image after cropping?

Tags: html, css

Is there a fix for cropping a round image from a square one that will get rid of my white border left behind.

I am trying to use animation css to rotate an earth image in a stary sky. Right now, I am struggling with a white border left over from cropping my image.
I don't have Photoshop right at the moment and I am having a hard time finding a free photo editor that will suffice. My macbook air 2016 model is supposed to have this feature in the preview mode, but it is not high-lit thus unavailable and I don't know why. Any help would be so appreciated it is ridiculous!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
       <!--animationlibrary githib url-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <img  id="starrySky" src="img/stary_nebula.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <img id="earth" name="earthRotate"  src="img/my_round_earth.jpg" alt=""/>

    <style>
        img{
            position: absolute;
            left: -10px;
            top: -15px;

            height: 175px;
            width: 175px;
        }

        **this is what I have now....**
        div#earth{

            transform: skew(20px, -10px);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            border-radius: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
         }
          img#earth{


            background-image: url("https://s.yimg.com/fz/api/res/1.2           /oaK.yDOhW_y44_tplykRWA--/YXBwaWQ9c3JjaGRkO2g9MTE2ODtxPTk1O3c9MTcwMA--/http://www.heavensgloryobservatory.com/Color_Jpegs/ngc2244NB03.jpg");
}
        #earth{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 600px;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            border-radius: 50%;
            -webkit-animation-name: earthOrbit;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
            overflow: visible;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes earthOrbit{
            from{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
            to{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        #starrySky{
            position: relative;
            top: -10px;
            left: -10px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your problem? can't simulate an image problem with random images from the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just specify what size the **parent <div>** has and use `overflow: hidden` if necessary.

**extra:** to crop in different shapes, just transform the **parent <div>**, e.g.:

- `transform: skew(20px, -10px)`,
- `transform: rotate(45deg)`,
- `border-radius: 50%`

Comment: Will this work if it is a circular image ? I know how to reduce a a square one.

Comment: yes. remember to use `border-radius: 50%` and the `width` equal to the `height` on the parent <div> for it to be a circle.

Comment: Thank you. I was sure there was something relatively simple to fix this.  I did not think about using border radius. Very clever my friend. Good fix!  I have not tried it yet, but I know html and css well enough to know it will work. I will rate your answer in a moment.

Comment: I can't test your code, because your images are private. And any image pulled from the web won't reproduce the cropping problem. A screenshot of your problem would be most explanatory, and then I could be able to help you out.

Comment: @user5474108 
editor buttons (on top of where you are typing) from left to right: [bold][italic][link][quote][code sample] **[image]** [code snippet]. To take a print screen (there's a button on your keyboard: normally close to NUM LOCK), then upload image to post via insert [image] option.

Comment: Okay, I got it. i used:  #earth{overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%; width:140px;height:140px;}. Then I resized my image to be 10 less pixels than the height and width of my <div> so the final image is 150px. The image is smaller than my container and overflow hidden gets rid of the white circle from my cropped image.

Comment: @user5474108 great

Comment: I know how to take a screen shot, for mac command, ctrl and 3, on a PC it is prntscrn and ctrl. I just don't see how to enter my screen shot to the site. Your previous entry is very difficult to read and is a grammatical nightmare. No offense...and it does not say how to upload my screen shot to my posted Q. The first sentence is anyway. Thank you for your help! I would not have got it without it. Happy coding!!! I don't know what you mean by image inset option. I'd have to be able to paste a file somewhere, and I don't see any place.

Comment: well let me explain again: when you click the edit button on your post. A textbox will appear. On top of that textbox there are editing options (like, bold, italic, insert code). The "mountain inside a rectangle" is the insert image button.